# I got this error with a clean binary: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '01010000 01010101 01010100 01000001'

Tags: python

I was developing a program to convert the content of a binary file to readable ACII. This is my code:

```
import struct
import base64
import codecs
import re
print("************Welcome to binary dumper and binary to ASCII decoder************")
print("Please only choose BINARY CONTENT files because otherwise an error will ocurr")
filename_ext = input("Enter filname to be dumped and decoded: ")
print("\n")
filename = input("Please enter the filename WITHOUT the extention: ")
print("\n")
print("Printing binary data...")
print("\n")
f = open(filename_ext, 'rb')
content = f.read()
f.close()
print(content)
contenttoconvert = input("Please copy the content that was output before and paste it here: ")
resubedcontent = re.sub("b|'", "", contenttoconvert)

padding = "=========".encode('utf-8')

base64_file_bytes = str(content).encode('utf-8')

a_binary_string = int(resubedcontent, 2)

binary_values = a_binary_string.split()
#Split string on whitespace

ascii_string = ""
for binary_value in binary_values:
    an_integer = float(binary_value)
#Convert to base 2 decimal integer


    ascii_character = chr(an_integer)
#Convert to ASCII character


    ascii_string += ascii_character
#Append character to `ascii_string`


print(ascii_string)

with open("output_" + filename, 'wb')as output:
    print("\n")
    print("Outputing file...")
    print("\n")
    decoded_file_data = base64.decodebytes(base64_file_bytes + padding)
    output.write(codecs.encode(decoded_file_data, 'hex_codec'))
```

The content of the file i read is this: 01010000 01010101 01010100 01000001
so i just remove the b of binary and the added semi quotes but it keeps saying the same. Hope i was clear.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? _so i just remove the b of binary and the added semi quotes_ What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that when you print or simply get a binary content in python it automaticaly add a b at the start of the binary  and simple quotes arround it.

Comment: I can't clarify what are you trying to do. You read from file binary string `01010000 01010101 01010100 01000001` and then convert _string_ to _int_. What for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that the string which you are asking user to copy paste (as well as the content of the file), contains blank spaces in between. Which is not a valid binary literal, so the error is expected.
If you change the content of your file to 01010000010101010101010001000001, then the above error will not be seen, or you can remove these spaces from within your code before going for int conversion.
Hope it helps.

Comment: And heads up for next error that is going to come, i.,e at line """binary_values = a_binary_string.split() """, as now you are trying to split an int value